# prestashop search by category and quantity of products

Tags: prestashop

I only reached:

```
$results = $db->executeS('
        SELECT cp.`id_product`
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp
        '.(Group::isFeatureActive() ? 'INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_group` cg ON cp.`id_category` = cg.`id_category`' : '').'
        INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category` c ON cp.`id_category` = c.`id_category`
        INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p ON cp.`id_product` = p.`id_product`
        '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p', false).'
        WHERE c.`active` = 1
        AND product_shop.`active` = 1
        AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "search")
        AND product_shop.indexed = 1
        '.$sql_groups);
```

I tried to change the query to classes/search.php but nothing has changed. Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a array with the id of the category you want use for filter search:

```
$fitersArray = array (//put the category you want filter);
$activeFilterString = implode($fitersArray, ',');


$results = $db->executeS('
        SELECT cp.`id_product`
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp
        '.(Group::isFeatureActive() ? 'INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_group` cg ON cp.`id_category` = cg.`id_category`' : '').'
        INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category` c ON cp.`id_category` = c.`id_category`
        INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p ON cp.`id_product` = p.`id_product`
        '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p', false).'
        WHERE c.`active` = 1
        AND product_shop.`active` = 1
        AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "search")
        AND c.`id_category` IN (' . $activeFilterString .')
        AND product_shop.indexed = 1
        '.$sql_groups);
```